# '_link' conflicting with '_trackEvent'

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to get both a `_trackEvent` push command and a `_link` to another domain command to work on a single quote button on my site, but am currently coming up with noting.

Here's the code:

```
<a href="URL"
target="_blank" 
onclick="
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Quotes', 'Click', 'QuoteImage']);
_gaq.push(['_link', 'URL']);
return false;
">button</a>
```

If I remove the `_link` push event from the code, the `_trackEvent` works, but I'm unable to get both to work at the same time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this doc : http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920

Try something like :

```
<a href="URL" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Quotes', 'Click', 'QuoteImage');return false;">
```

and

```
function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action, opt_label) {
try {
var myTracker=_gat._getTrackerByName();
_gaq.push(['myTracker._trackEvent', category , action, opt_label ]);
_gaq.push(['_link', link.href]);
}catch(err){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do what you are trying to do, but using jquery to track the event by ID in the href, while linking / passing the cookie to another domain.

See related thread here:

[Site is showing up as a referrer to its own domain in Google Analytics reports. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488523/site-is-showing-up-as-a-referrer-to-its-own-domain-in-google-analytics-reports)

Please do post your solution if you figure it out.

I'm still trying to do the same thing for href links as well as form submit buttons ... can't get it to work; our domain still showing as referrer for conversions instead of the original traffic source -- as 3rd party ecomm cart checkout is writing new cookie ... can't get it to link, orig referrer is lost ... and of course want to track click event as well.